# Recursively import all .py files from all folders

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, import, python-3.4

Given one root directory, I need to import all files from all folders (and folders inside other folders) under the root directory.

I figured this could maybe be done with the help of `os.walk()`, but no idea how to import the files after "walking" through them.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To import a module by name (in 3.4), use `importlib.load_module`, which is a "simplifying wrapper around `importlib.__import__`".  You will see the latter mentioned (as a builtin) in other answers.  To be useful, you must, of course, assign each module returned to *something* -- unless you are importing merely to check syntax or generate .pyc files, as in the compile_all module.