# How do I dynamically import all *.py files from a given directory AND all sub-directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a bunch of Python files underneath one common directory, but within that, an arbitrary number of sub-directories may exist:

```
/first/foo.py
/first/bar.py
/first/fizz/buzz.py
/first/numbers/one.py
/first/numbers/two.py
```

I have some arbitrary files where I want to import all of these. Manually, I could do:

```
import first.foo
import first.bar
import first.fizz.buzz
import first.numbers.one
import first.numbers.two
```

But instead I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
import_everything_under('first')
```

I know that a similar question has already popped up: [Recursively import all .py files from all folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945764/recursively-import-all-py-files-from-all-folders)

But the given answers and alleged duplicates do NOT answer this question.

---

This question was flagged as a possible duplicate of: [How to load all modules in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431)

Again, that does NOT answer this question. The answer given to that question is not recursive - it would ONLY import items from the immediate directory and does NOT include scripts in sub-directories, which I need for my use-case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load all modules in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What about creating `first/__init__.py` and then import all the relevant modules there (+ similarly for all sub-modules)?

Comment: @a_guest I know it's definitely an unusual use-case but it's brought on due to the way a dependency framework I'm using is set up. Essentially it allows a sort of "plugin" system where it loads scripts to affect its behavior from a specific directory - but ONLY that directory. It does not allow sub-directories, which makes organization at scale a huge pain.

So I want a single script in that main directory that can dynamically load my own scripts from any arbitrary directory structure that I define.

I could just "manually" import any modules I need, but that's also a maintenance chore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is broken up into two steps (from my point of view):

1. Walk through your directories and sub-directories and find the names of all the .py files you want to import
2. Import them!

To solve (1), we can use the `os.walk` method to find all the .py files. This function would look like this:

```py
import os
def get_py_files(src):
    cwd = os.getcwd() # Current Working directory
    py_files = [] 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".py"):
                py_files.append(os.path.join(cwd, root, file))
    return py_files
```

Now that you have a list of your .py files, we need a function that can dynamically import them.

```py
import importlib
def dynamic_import(module_name, py_path):
    module_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, py_path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(module_spec)
    module_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```

And now we just need to put it all together, writing a function that calls your `get_py_files` function and then loops over the results, loading the modules with `dynamic_import`.

**I am assuming you want the module names that you use in your python script to be the same as the file name, however you can change that by modifying the `module_name` variable in the function below.**

```py
def dynamic_import_from_src(src, star_import = False):
    my_py_files = get_py_files(src)
    for py_file in my_py_files:
        module_name = os.path.split(py_file)[-1].strip(".py")
        imported_module = dynamic_import(module_name, py_file)
        if star_import:
            for obj in dir(imported_module):
                globals()[obj] = imported_module.__dict__[obj]
        else:
            globals()[module_name] = imported_module
    return
```

Notice we have to call `globals()` to add the module to the global namespace. Without doing this, the module will be imported but you will have no way of accessing anything inside it. You can pass `star_import = True` to `dynamic_import_from_src` if you want it to be a star import instead. (like `from first.foo import *`. Note that this may overwrite variables in your namespace but that's one of the cons of using the `*` import anyways.

Throwing it all in one block so it's easier to see it all at once:

```py
import os
import importlib


def get_py_files(src):
    cwd = os.getcwd() # Current Working directory
    py_files = [] 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".py"):
                py_files.append(os.path.join(cwd, root, file))
    return py_files


def dynamic_import(module_name, py_path):
    module_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, py_path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(module_spec)
    module_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module


def dynamic_import_from_src(src, star_import = False):
    my_py_files = get_py_files(src)
    for py_file in my_py_files:
        module_name = os.path.split(py_file)[-1].strip(".py")
        imported_module = dynamic_import(module_name, py_file)
        if star_import:
            for obj in dir(imported_module):
                globals()[obj] = imported_module.__dict__[obj]
        else:
            globals()[module_name] = imported_module
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dynamic_import_from_src("first", star_import = False)
```

At this point, you can access any of the modules you imported the exact same way as if you did `import first.whatever`. For example, if `first/numbers/one.py` contained `x=1`, then you would be able to access that by saying `one.x`.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it should work. Marked as accepted.

Comment: @glenn.barker I made a few changes. I accidentally overwrote the builtin keyword, `dir` in some of the functions so I replaced that with `src` instead. Also added the ability to simulate `*` imports in `dynamic_import_from_src`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciated. I also found my own solution while you were typing up yours so I also shared what I found as a separate answer. I think either solution should work here so we'll have both to include for future reference. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @SyntaxVoid should work but in parallel I've been tinkering at this problem myself, and I think I've found another way of doing it. Either my own solution or @SyntaxVoid's solution should work, I believe.

```
from importlib import util
from os import path
from glob import glob


def import_submodules(start_path, include_start_directory=True):
    start_path = path.abspath(start_path)
    pattern = '**/*.py' if include_start_directory else '*/**/*.py'
    py_files = [f for f in glob(path.join(start_path, pattern), recursive=True) if not f.endswith('__.py')]

    for py_file in py_files:
        spec = util.spec_from_file_location('', py_file)
        module = util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I don't know that this way is alright. But, try that.

from first import *

Comment: This does not recursively import from sub-directories and thus does not suit the needs of this question.